# call parent constructor in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, constructor, initialization, new-operator

How can I call parents constructor ?

```
module C
    attr_accessor :c, :cc
    def initialization c, cc
        @c, @cc = c, cc
    end 
end

class B
    attr_accessor :b, :bb
    def initialization b, bb
        @b, @bb = b, bb
    end 
end


class A < B
    include C
    attr_accessor :a, :aa
    def initialization (a, b, c, aa, bb, cc)
        #call B::initialization - ?
        #call C::initialization - ?
        @a, @aa = a, aa
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it idiomatic for a module to have an `initialize` method?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, probably, no. You are right. I was just starting ruby in April 2010 ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, your method should be `initialize`, not `initialization`. Then, you can use `super` to call the parent class method. As for calling `C`'s initializer in `A`, for clarity, I'd recommend splitting the initialization stuff into a different function, then just calling that function directly. It's easy to implement, and clearer.

Comment: i know you got the answer right by saying you use super, but for someone that is super new to ruby I just did not know until i looked at lower examples.

Comment: Code examples are always more helpful.

Answer (score 45):

Ruby doesn't have constructors, therefore it's obviously not possible to call them, parent or otherwise. Ruby *does* have methods, however, and in order to call the parent's method with the same name as the currently executing method, you can use the `super` keyword. [Note: `super` without arguments is a shortcut for passing the same arguments that were passed into the currently executing method. If you actually want to pass *no* arguments, you have to do so explicitly: `super()`.]

Comment: @Jörg, +1. Thanks for the mention of the shortcut. Overriding methods just became so much more elegant :)

Comment: With regards to "passing the same arguments": If you do `a = 42` before using `super` without brackets, it'll use the new object referred to by `a`, not the old one.

Comment: What do you mean by "ruby doesn't have constuctors"?

Comment: @Leopd: Can you clarify your question? I'm not really sure what's unclear about that statement.

Comment: How does the `initialize` method differ from a construtor?  It's a method that gets called when an object is created -- it quacks like a duck.

Comment: @Leopd: the `initialize` method differs from a constructor in that it is a method, not a constructor.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Constructor:  Class Method that creates objects.  Initialize:  Class Method that creates objects.  ???  Quack Quack?  I still don't see the difference.  Is there something in the definition of constructor that I'm missing?

Comment: @alex0112 As far as i know **new** is ruby constructor not **initialize**. Actually **initialize** can't create object. it's **new** that create solid new object and  internally call **initialize** for initialization. Of course always welcome to let me know if i am wrong  :)

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon: *If* there even *were* something like a "constructor" in Ruby, then it would be `Class#allocate`, not `Class#new`. `Class#allocate` creates a new object. `Class#new` is simply a convenience method calls `Class#allocate` and then `#initialize`.

Comment: @alex0112: Yes. You are missing that a constructor is not a method. But all of `Class#new`, `Class#allocate` and `#initialize` are methods. Constructors have special rules about when they are allowed to be called, how they are allowed to be inherited, what they are allowed to contain etc. For example, in Java, constructors must call the parent constructor, and if they don't, that call gets automatically inserted by the compiler.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank for clear my misconception, but what is actually constructor or does ruby has  any constructor ? I am really confused about this.

Comment: "Ruby doesn't have constructors" this is more like a computer science trivia answer than actual useful information... initialize is a constructor for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @ParkerKemp: In all languages I know of that have constructors (e.g. C++, Java, Scala, C#, Ceylon, Kotlin, D, Eiffel), constructors have three important properties: 1) they construct objects (duh!), 2) they are not associated with any instance (obviously, since they have to construct it first), 3) they are a separate language construct from other callable constructs (e.g. functions, procedures, methods). Even in ECMAScript, where constructors are just functions, they are invoked with a special operator and in that case behave differently from functions. `initialize` is none of that. It doesn't

Comment: … automatically transfers to `initialize` *because it is just a method like any other*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't disagree with any of that, except that it's important for newcomers to understand. The distinctions you draw, while technically correct, are not going to matter to someone new to ruby, and _especially_ not to someone new to programming in general. As I said, for all intents and purposes `initialize` can be viewed as a constructor.

Answer (score 37):

Use the `super` method! Ruby does not have multiple inheritance though.

```
class B

  attr_accessor :b, :bb

  def initialize(b, bb)
    @b, @bb = b, bb
  end

end

module C

end

class A < B
  include C  # <= if C was a class, you'd get: TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

  attr_accessor :a, :aa

  def initialize(a,b,aa,bb)
    @a, @aa = a, aa
    super(b, bb)  # <= calls B#initialize
  end

end

a = A.new(1,2,3,4)
puts a.inspect # => #<A:0x42d6d8 @aa=3, @a=1, @b=2, @bb=4>
```

Answer (score 8):

This code below will print :

A.proc1
B.proc1
C.proc1

```
module A
  def proc1
    puts "A.proc1"
    super
  end
end

class B
  def proc1
    puts "B.proc1"
  end
end

class C < B
  include A
  def proc1
    super
    puts "C.proc1"
  end
end

C.new.proc1
```